# How does the LSTM know number of time steps and features in an Conv1D-LSTM network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have a time series signal (n samples, each sample has 81 time steps and 3 features = n x 81 x 3).
I am using an conv1D-LSTM network.  n_timesteps = 81, n_features = 3.
Normal LSTM specifies both n_timesteps and n_features, however when combined with conv1d, these are not specified.

1. How does the LSTM know how many time steps and features there are in the input to it?
2. How does the LSTM know the end of the sequence for each sample?
3. Are the time steps "stored up" and them fed into the LSTM or are the processed one time step at a time and fed into the LSTM one time step at a time?
4. If I include the "flatten" (below) it fails.  Why?
5. Do the number of filters in the conv1d have to correspond to the number of filters in the LSTM?

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
#model.add(Flatten())

#model.add(LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(units=32, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1 and 2

Everything is based on tensors (sort of like matrices, but with any number of dimensions).

The tensors have shapes and everything is based on the shapes. Your data tensors are three-dimensional: `(samples, time_steps, features)`.

It happens that 1D convolutions also use the same 3D tensors: `(samples, length, channels)`. So:

- samples = examples = sequences
- time_steps = length
- features = channels

There is no secret. The data is structured and the layers will use this structure. Look at your `model.summary()` and see the number of steps and features for every layer's output.

## 3

There is no interleaving between layers.

- The conv layer will process its entire input tensor and generate an output tensor.
- The next conv layer will take this entire output and produce another entire output
- The LSTM layer will do the same, take an entire input and output an entire tensor.

## 4

If you flatten the data, your 3D tensors `(samples, steps, feats)` will become 2D tensors `(samples, something)`. No more data structure that can be understood by the layers.

## 5

There is absolutely no requirement for number of filters or units. The only thing is that the final output of your model needs to have the same shape of your `y_train` data.

Here is my model summary.  It appears that the number of features has changed from the original 3 (of the input) to 32 (for the conv1d).  Is it correct that the LSTM will now process then entire time steps (~81) on the 32 features of the conv1d instead of the 3 features of the input?

## Example of summary:

The first LSTM will take an input shape of `(None, 38,32)`. This means this LSTM will process:

- 38 steps
- 32 features

The convolutions are discarding border steps and the maxpooling is halving the steps.

````
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 79, 32)            320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 77, 32)            3104      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 77, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 38, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 38, 128)           82432     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 38, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 38, 64)            49408     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                12416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 16)                528       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 148,225
Trainable params: 148,225
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________```
````

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  Here is my model summary.  It seems to say it has changed the feature size from the original 3 to the conv1d feature map of 32?  I guess the LSTM will now process the time steps of the 32 features insterad of the original 3 features.  Is that correct?  Thanks, Jon

Comment: Notice how the convolutions are reducing the steps. The LSTM will process a sequence of 38 steps.